# How can I revive a phantom text?

Tags: lyx

In LyX, I made a certain section "phantom". Now I want to bring it back to normal.

I tried right-clicking on the text and un-checking the "Phantom" option, but it didn't have any effect.

I also looked in Edit->Text Style, but found nothing that seems related.

How can I bring my text back to life?

---

EDIT: Here is an MWE. To create a phantom, I just selected the entire text and then went to the menus: Insert -> Formatting -> Phantom -> Phantom. I have LyX 2.1.2 on Ubuntu.

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\options ,section
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command bibtex
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 0
\use_package amssymb 0
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plainnat
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2.9cm
\rightmargin 2.9cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 2
\paperpagestyle headings
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
abc
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
123
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
456
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
789
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
def
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Can you open the LyX file with an external editor and change the markup?

Comment: I can probably open it with a text editor. Is this the best solution?

Comment: Maybe not, but it may be the easiest and quickest one. I suppose LyX uses just markup so the code should be easily to spot in the file.

Comment: Hi Erel, next time please give more details. Instead of "I made a certain section 'phantom'", you could give the steps that you took to make a section phantom. Second, please consider giving a minimum working example (see here for more info: wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample). There might be several ways to make a phantom, and I'm not sure which one you did. Finally, consider posting the version number of LyX that you use.

Answer (score 3):

First way: place the cursor *just* inside the phantom inset (so as far as possible to the left, but inside the inset) as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

You can see that the cusor is nested two levels because there are two sets of framing brackets.

Then press "backspace".

Second way: place the cursor anywhere inside the phantom inset, and then go to Edit > Dissolve Inset.

Comment: In both methods, the text comes back to life, but all the formatting are gone. See the MWE I added to the question.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi ah, now I see what you mean. The formatting is lost when you create the phantom, not when you remove it. I do not know much about this, but my guess is that it is a bug in LyX that we let you create a phantom if you have nested insets. Could you please post a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac ?

Comment: So it is not possible to hide text which contains nested insets?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I have no idea. I would be interested in the answer to that myself. You might consider posting another question. Once we get the answer for LaTeX we can think about how to do it in LyX. Also note that support for phantom is relatively new in LyX so it is not surprising that it is not well polished.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi thank you for opening a bug report. For reference, it was opened here: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9353.